# force telegram ios app to open url in external safari browser

Tags: ios, iphone, telegram

We have a problem with the built-in Telegram browser, when a user clicks on URLs in an iPhone Telegram chats, is it possible to force Telegram to open specific URLs in external browser?

I also tried to use this library to detect browser but it doesn't work:
http://zeno.github.io/mobile-detect-demo/

Comment: Please post more information. The URL schema you are using and such.

Comment: an example is: http://360ideas.ir/vtour/Arvan%20Tour.html this url works well in safari but have many problems in telegram browser and we want prevent telegram to open it in inetrnal browser.

Comment: I also have this problem on Android. This feature causes some problems for those of our users that don't know how to open the link in a special app (that we want). Is there a special form of `URL` that Telegram doesn't open it in its in-app browser?